# Gradle pass cmd line argument to war

Tags: java, variables, tomcat, gradle, arguments

I want to generate my war file (to deploy in tomcat) and pass a variable, and I want to use that variable inside my logback.xml file.

something like this:

```
gradle build -Dlocation="/home/folderX"
```

and then, inside logback.xml, I want to do something like this:

```
<property name="LOG_PATH" value="$location" />
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'war'

processResources {
    filesMatching('logback.xml') {
        expand(['location':project.property('location')])
    }
}
```

Invoke it using

```
gradlew -Plocation=foo build
```

logback.xml is assumed to be in src/main/resources in this example.